# Maven changing the maven repository from {user}/.m2/repository to projectfolder using pom.xml

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I am just wondering is it possible to change the repository from m2 to my project folder using pom.xml setting?

Or is there another self contained way to do it, except using settings.xml from maven??

Cheers,
Andrei

Comment: If you can give details of why you need this, perhaps someone can suggest alternate ways to achieve it.

Comment: I want to have a self contained project because its a team of 7 working on it, it would be beneficial to be able to put it in svn even the jars.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comment, it appears that you want the dependencies to be downloaded once, checked into version control system and never updated again.

While this is possible, this would defeat the purpose of using maven - like handling updates to dependencies.  Also, it would bloat your SCM needlessly and cause performance issues during checkouts.

Why don't you look at using a repository manager (like [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)), which can mirror required repositories in your local network, so that developers can access it instead of downloading it from internet?

Comment: i get what you are saying, that would be a good idea but do not have the facilities required to do that. ideally it should download all the jars from maven central but I have a few I added manually I will just try to find them on a maven rep and should be ok